# What should I know about half vectorization and Kronecker product to do this matrix differentation?

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-calculus

I have a scalar function as follows:
\begin{equation*}
 \ell(\beta, \Sigma, \mu, \Lambda) = \sum_{i=1}^{m} \left[\boldsymbol{y}_{i}^{T} \left(X_{i}\beta + Z_{1} \mu_{i} \right) - \boldsymbol{1}_{i}^{T} B\left(X_{i}\beta + Z_{i}\mu_{i}, \operatorname{dg}\left(Z_{i}\Lambda_{i}Z_{i}^{T} \right) \right) + \boldsymbol{1}_{i}^{T} c(\boldsymbol{y}_{i})\\ +\frac{1}{2}\left\{\log \left|\Sigma^{-1}\Lambda_{i} \right| - \mu_{i}^{T}\Sigma^{-1}\mu_{i} - \operatorname{tr}\left(\Sigma^{-1}\Lambda_{i} \right) \right\} + \frac{K}{2} \right] 
\end{equation*}

where for $1 \le i \le m$

$
\mu_{i}: K \times 1 \text{vectors}
$

$ 
\Lambda_{i}: K \times K \text{matrices}
$

$
\boldsymbol{y}_{i}: \begin{bmatrix}y_{i1} & \ldots & y_{in_{i}}  \end{bmatrix}^{T}, n_{i} \times 1 \text{vectors}
$

$
\boldsymbol{1}_{i}: \begin{bmatrix}1, \ldots , 1  \end{bmatrix}^{T}
$

$
\Sigma: K\times K \text{positive definite matrix}
$

$
X_{i}, Z_{i}: \text{design matrices in regression models}
$

$
B(\mu, \sigma^{2}) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} b(\sigma x + \mu)\phi(x) \, dx, \text{ where }  \phi(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp \left(-x^{2}/2 \right), b(\cdot) \text{ is any differentiable function.}
$

$
\operatorname{dg}\left(A\right): \text{for a square matrix } A, \text{ returns a column vector containing the diagonal entries of }A.
$

---

So the paper suggests that if $D_{p}$ denote the *duplication matrix* of order $p$ defined through the relationship $\operatorname{vec}\left( A \right) = D_{p}\operatorname{vech}\left(A \right)$ for a symmetric $p \times p$ matrix $A$. Then
$$
\frac{\partial \ell}{\partial \operatorname{vech}\left(\Sigma \right)} = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^{m} \operatorname{vec} \left\{\Sigma^{-1} \left(\mu_{i}\mu_{i}^{T} + \Lambda_{i} \right)\Sigma^{-1} - \Sigma^{-1} \right\}^{T}D_{K}
$$
and
$$
\frac{\partial^{2} \ell}{\partial \operatorname{vech}\left( \Sigma \right) \partial \operatorname{vech}\left( \Lambda_{i}\right)} = \frac{1}{2} D_{K}^{T}\left(\Sigma^{-1}\otimes \Sigma^{-1}  \right)D_{K}.
$$

What concepts should I know so as to get my head around these calculations? (I actually need these for Newton-Raphson algorithm, optimizing over $\left(\beta, \operatorname{vech}\left( \Sigma\right), \mu_{1}, \operatorname{vech}\left(\Lambda_{1}\right), \ldots , \mu_{m}, \operatorname{vech}\left(\Lambda_{m}\right) \right)$.)

Comment: I suggest you look into the book "Matrix Differential Calculus with Applications in Statistics and Econometrics" by Magnus and Neudecker. (https://www.janmagnus.nl/misc/mdc-ch18.pdf). In section 3.8 they explain the duplication matrix, and in section 15.8 it shows how these can be used to find the expected Hessian of the loglikelihood (Fisher information).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a very complicated function, but I'll show you how to find the first result.

Start by taking the differential of the function, assuming all of the variables (except for $\Sigma),\,$ are constant and so the differentials of those terms are zero 
$$\eqalign{
 d\ell &= \frac{1}{2}\sum_i \Big[d(\log\det(\Sigma^{-1}\Lambda_i)) - d(\mu_i\mu_i^T:\Sigma^{-1}) - d(\Lambda_i:\Sigma^{-1})\Big] \cr
 &= \frac{1}{2}\sum_i \Big[d({\rm tr}\log(\Sigma^{-1}\Lambda_i)) - d(\mu_i\mu_i^T:\Sigma^{-1}) - d(\Lambda_i:\Sigma^{-1})\Big] \cr
 &= \frac{1}{2}\sum_i \Big[(\Sigma^{-1}\Lambda_i)^{-T}:(d\Sigma^{-1}\Lambda_i) - \mu_i\mu_i^T:d\Sigma^{-1} - \Lambda_i:d\Sigma^{-1}\Big] \cr
 &= \frac{1}{2}\sum_i \Big[(\Sigma^T\Lambda_i^{-T})\Lambda_i^T - \mu_i\mu_i^T - \Lambda_i\Big]:d\Sigma^{-1} \cr
 &= \frac{1}{2}\sum_i \Big[-\Sigma^T + \mu_i\mu_i^T + \Lambda_i\Big]:\Sigma^{-1}\,d\Sigma\,\Sigma^{-1} \cr
 &= \frac{1}{2}\sum_i \Big[\Sigma^{-T}(\mu_i\mu_i^T + \Lambda_i)\Sigma^{-T}-\Sigma^{-T} \Big]:d\Sigma \cr\cr
}$$
Now use some of the properties of vec/vech 
$$\eqalign{
 A:B &= {\rm vec}(A)^T{\rm vec}(B) \cr
 {\rm vec}(X) &= D_p {\rm vech}(X) \cr
}$$ to recast the last line as
$$\eqalign{
 d\ell &= \frac{1}{2}\sum_i {\rm vec}\Big[\Sigma^{-T}(\mu_i\mu_i^T + \Lambda_i)\Sigma^{-T}-\Sigma^{-T} \Big]^T\Big(D_K{\rm vech}(d\Sigma)\Big) \cr
}$$
You can simplify this further using $(\Sigma^T=\Sigma)$, to obtain the first derivative (aka gradient) in your question.

To get the mixed second derivative, take the differential of the gradient. This time assume that all variables except for the $\Lambda_i$ are constant.

Comment: Thanks for your response! But from your 4th equation to 5th, going from $d \Sigma^{-1}$ to $d \Sigma$, could you please explain how you can multiply $\Sigma^{-1}$ twice before and after the differential and how why the first term was multiplied my $(-1)$?

Comment: The differential of the inverse of a matrix is a well-known result. $$d\Sigma^{-1} = -\Sigma^{-1}\,d\Sigma\,\Sigma^{-1}$$You can derive it for yourself by differentiating the equation $$\Sigma\,\Sigma^{-1}=I$$